# How can I make a custom image from the score of my app with swift? to share

Tags: ios, swift

I was using

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(view.frame.size)
view.layer.renderInContext(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext())
let screenshot = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
```

to share a screenshot of the score the user made in the game but I saw some apps that share a custom image with the score the user made, and I really can't find how to make that custom image

Comment: what you mean with custom image? please add code or screenshot or any other info that can help us to understand your problem

Comment: sorry, I am new here, but @codester just answer my question, thanks any way :)

Comment: glad that problem solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make your custom `UIView` and than set the score in it's label and use above code.You do not need to show your customView.It's just to take snapshot.

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(customView.frame.size)
customView.layer.renderInContext(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext())
let screenshot = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
```